# PHP mysqli query result repeats last row when returning multiple rows

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi all I have the following function:

```
Function Query($sql, $parameters, &$results, $result_types = null)
{
    if($this->debug)
        $this->OutputDebug('Query: '.$sql);
    $results = array();
    $statement = $this->db->stmt_init();
    if(!$statement->prepare($sql))
        return $this->SetError($statement->error);
    $prepared = array();
    $types = '';
    $tp = count($parameters);
    $v = $parameters;
    for($p = 0; $p < $tp;)
    {
        switch($t = $v[$p++])
        {
            case 's':
            case 'i':
            case 'd':
                $v[$p] = (IsSet($v[$p]) ? $v[$p] : null);
                break;
            case 'b':
                $v[$p] = (IsSet($v[$p]) ? ($v[$p] ? 'Y' : 'N') : null);
            case 't':
            case 'dt':
            case 'ts':
                $t = 's';
                break;
        }
        $types .= $t;
        if($this->debug)
            $this->OutputDebug('Query parameter type: '.$t.' value: '.$v[$p]);
        $prepared[] = &$v[$p++];
    }
    array_unshift($prepared, $types);
    if(!call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $prepared)
    || !$statement->execute())
    {
        $error = $statement->error;
        $statement->close();
        return $this->SetError($error);
    }
    $fields = $statement->field_count;
    if($fields)
    {
        $row = $bind = array();
        for($f = 0; $f < $fields; ++$f)
        {
            $row[$f] = null;
            $bind[$f] = &$row[$f];
        }
        if(!call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_result'), $bind))
        {
            $statement->close();
            return $this->SetError($statement->error);
        }
        $rows = array();
        $i = 0;
        while(($success = $statement->fetch()) !== null)
        {
            if(!$success)
            {
                $statement->close();
                return $this->SetError($statement->error);
            }
            if(IsSet($result_types))
            {
                $tc = count($result_types);
                for($c = 0; $c < $tc; ++$c)
                {
                    if(!IsSet($row[$c]))
                        continue;
                    switch($result_types[$c])
                    {
                        case 'b':
                            $row[$c] = ($row[$c] === 'Y');
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        $results['rows'] = $rows;
    }
    elseif(strlen($error = $statement->error))
    {
        $statement->close();
        return $this->SetError($error);
    }
    else
    {
        $results['insert_id'] = $statement->insert_id;
        $results['affected_rows'] = $statement->affected_rows;
    }
    $statement->close();
    return true;
}
```

Now lets assume a simple table called roster as follows:

- id      player      team
- 116        6          2
- 117        6          3
- 118        3          5

Now lets call the function:

```
$parameters = array(            
    'i', 0
);
$result_types = array('i');
$this->Query( 'SELECT id FROM roster WHERE player != ? ORDER BY id', $parameters, $results, $result_types);
```

From this I would expect to get 116, 117 & 118 returned as part of the array from $results.  Instead I get 118, 118 & 118!!

A print_r(array_values($results)); returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 118 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 118 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 118 ) ) )
```

What have I done wrong here please?

Comment: This function is the most terrible piece of code I've ever seen.

Comment: I totally agree which is why I'm struggling with it.  It's part of a class written by someone else!

Comment: Well don't use it as it doesn't work

Comment: I'm using it because it's part of the "PHP OAuth Library" over on PHPclasses and for that it seems to work - but only because in that environment it only ever returns one (1) result and consequently never goes wrong!

Comment: Do you mean it only fails if you select (1) field ? or (1) result row ?

Comment: Whether you select one or more fields it returns a result.  However it only returns one row correctly - more rows and they all equal the same.  So if you only ever return one row (irrelevant of how many fields) it looks as if it's working; you don't notice the fault.  It fails on more than one row.